# Import not found when added as sub directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I've cloned https://github.com/sarathknv/adversarial-pytorch. The file one_pixel.py finds all imports but If I add adversarial-pytorch as a sub directory to an existing project - myproject -> other -> adversarial-pytorch I receive error :

```
from model import BasicCNN
```

causes error :

> Unresolved reference BasicCNN

I've tried modifying the import line to :

```
from myproject.other.model import BasicCNN
```

but this does not fix issue.

How to import python files that exist as a sub-project ?

Comment: Can you give the full traceback of your exception?

Comment: This import might only work for installed packages or if they reside in the same directory as your script. Where are the model.py and your own module located and can you run merely `import model`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to add "myproject/other" to the system path like following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('yourpathstring')
from model import BasicCNN
```

Comment: this didnt work for me...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add __init__.py file to every directory you want to import modules from.
Good luck!

Comment: This is not true for python versions >3.3

Answer (score 0):

Should have mentioned im using PyCharm. This also fixes issue :

From PyCharm : "File" -> "Settings" -> "Project Structure" -> add myproject/other as a source folder.